# Is there some way to assume @Nullable as default? (using FindBugs or any other free tool)

Tags: java, static-analysis, nullable

Consider such code

```
public void m1(String text) {
    if(text == null)
        text = "<empty>";

    System.out.println(text.toLowerCase());
}
```

And this is a buggy version:

```
public void m1(String text) {
    System.out.println(text.toLowerCase());
}
```

If null value passed, the NullPointerException may be thrown. I would like the static-analysis tool (e.g. FindBugs) to report this issue. Unsuccessfully the FindBugs (at least by default) requires me to specify @Nullable annotation explicitly.

```
public void m1(@Nullable String text) {
    System.out.println(text.toLowerCase()); // FindBugs: text must be nonnull but is marked as nullable
}
```

The problem is that if I forget to annotate it, the bug will be missed!!!

How can I make the FindBugs (or any other free tool) to assume @Nullable by default?

Comment: But I believed we told you it's *FindBugs*, not Firebug ;)

Comment: Oh.. Sorry, fixed the question... Reflex :-)

Comment: BTW, it seems to be @DefaultAnnotationForParameters, but can't get it to work.

Comment: so your code throwing around NPE is perfectly cromulent?  Isn't that the world upside-down? Why not add @NotNull everywhere and make it so that you code **cannot** ever pass a *null* to that method?   A little non-scientific *find / cat / grep NotNull/Nullable* here yelded around 5000 uses for @NotNull and... well, only 400 for @Nullable (and honestly most of these 400 nullables are poor code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Javadoc](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/DefaultAnnotationForParameters.html):

> `@DefaultAnnotationForParameters` indicates that all members of the class or package should be annotated with the default value of the supplied annotation class.

(BTW Javadocs for `@DefaultAnnotation`, `@DefaultAnnotationForFields` and `@DefaultAnnotationForMethods` contain exactly the same text).

But according to [chapter 10 of FindBugs Manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html):

> This is same as the DefaultAnnotation except it only applys to method parameters.

While theroretically either

```
@DefaultAnnotationForParameters(value = Nullable.class)
```

or

```
@DefaultAnnotationForParameters({Nullable.class})
```

should work, **both don't**.

<strike>I don't know if FindBugs supports this but</strike> with [JSR 305](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.html) you can also use `@ParametersAreNullableByDefault` annotation applied to a package, class or method. [Unfortunately FindBugs 1.3.9 ignores @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault and similar annotations (used on packages or on types).](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2870641&group_id=96405&atid=614693)

Comment: Does it work for your? If yes, what is your version (mine FindBug 1.3.9)?

Comment: Tried 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9. I added annotations for class and for package (using package-info.java) - no luck...

Comment: perhaps CheckForNull.class will work better as the default annotation

Comment: @alex2k8: I've updated the answer. @DefaultAnnotationForParameters works like it's supposed to with some other nullness annotations, but I had no luck with Nullable either.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own detector in FindBugs that looks for any use of parameters that are not null checked. Would be relatively simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is @ParametersAreNullableByDefault (http://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.java) but I would urge you to use @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault instead. It would also have detected your buggy code. Preferably, you put them in your package-info.java file as an annotation on the package.